# Prove that if $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k f_k$ converges unconditionally.

Tags: functional-analysis

I would like to prove the following:

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. If $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k f_k$ converges unconditionally for all $\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

My attempt. Recall that if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_{\sigma(k)}$ is convergent for all permutations $\sigma$, we say that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f_k$ is unconditionally convergent. Moreover, if $\left\{f_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a Bessel sequence in $\mathcal{H}$, then the operator
$$
T:\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k f_k
$$
is a well-defined bounded operator from $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ into $\mathcal{H}$.  Let us consider then $T\left\{c_{\sigma(k)}\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty} $. Hence,
\begin{aligned}
\left\| T\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{n}-T\left\{c_{\sigma(k)}\right\}_{k=1}^{m} \right\| &=\sup _{\|g\|=1}\left|\left\langle T\left\{c_k\right\}_{k=1}^{n}- T\left\{c_{\sigma(k)}\right\}_{k=1}^{m},g\right\rangle\right| \\
&=\sup _{\|g\|=1}\left|\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^n c_{k} f_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^m c_{\sigma(k)} f_{\sigma(k)}, g\right\rangle\right|
\end{aligned}
It seemed like a good idea but I don't know now what to do with the last step.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you!

Comment: [This](https://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-22-1/22J1Besse.pdf) may be of interest to you

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for the delay. I was studying your solution :-) thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to show that $\sum_kc_k f_k$ converges in $H$ since for any permutation $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{N}$,  $(f_{\sigma(k)}:k\in\mathbb{N})$ is a Bessel sequence whenever $(f_k)$ is. Indeed,
\begin{align}
\sum_k|\langle x,f_k\rangle|^2=\sum_k|\langle x,f_{\sigma(k)}\rangle|^2\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}

Suppose then that
$$ \Big(\sum_k|\langle x,f_k\rangle|^2\Big)^{1/2}\leq B\|x\|_H, \qquad x\in H.$$

For any $m<n$
\begin{align}\Big\|\sum^n_{k=m}c_kf_k\Big\|_H&=\sup_{g\in H: \|g\|_H=1}\Big|\langle\sum^n_{k=m}c_kf_k,g\rangle\Big|\leq\sup_{g\in H: \|g\|_H=1}\sum^n_{k=m}|c_k||\langle f_k,g\rangle|\\
&\leq\sup_{g\in H:\|g\|_H=1} \Big(\sum^n_{k=m}|c_k|^2\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\sum^n_{k=m}|\langle f_k,g\rangle|^2\Big)^{1/2}\leq B\Big(\sum^n_{k=m}|c_k|^2\Big)^{1/2}\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}

From this, it follows that $\sum^n_{k=1}c_kf_k$ defines a Cauchy sequence in $H$ and so, it converges. A similar computation shows that
$$\|\sum_k c_kf_k\|_H\leq B\|c\|_{\ell_2}$$

Finally, fix a permutation $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{N}$. To show that
$$x=\sum_kc_kf_k=\sum_jc_{\sigma(k)}f_{\sigma(k)}$$
set $s_n=\sum^n_{k=1}c_kf_k$ and $t_n=\sum^n_{k=1}c_{\sigma(k)}f_{\sigma(k)}$
We have shown that $\lim_n\|x-s_n\|_H=0$. From \eqref{two},
given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N$ so that
$$\|x-s_n\|^2_H\leq B^2\sum_{k>n}|c_k|^2<\varepsilon^2/4, \qquad n\geq N$$
Then
$$\|x-t_n\|^2_H\leq 2\|x-s_n\|^2_H+2\|s_n-t_n\|^2_H<2\|x-s_n\|^2_H + \varepsilon^2/2
$$
Choose $M\geq N$ large enough so that $\{1,\ldots,N\}\subset\{\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(M)\}$. Then, for $n\geq M$
\begin{align}
|t_n-s_n\|^2_H&=\|c_{\sigma(1)}f_{\sigma(1)}+\ldots +c_{\sigma(n)}f_{\sigma(n)}-c_1f_1-\ldots - c_nf_n\|^2_H\\
&\leq B^2\sum_{k>N}|c_k|^2<\varepsilon^2/4
\end{align}
which follows again from \eqref{two} since all terms $c_jf_j$ with $1\leq j\leq N$ get cancelled.

Putting things together we get that for $n\geq M$,
$\|t_n-x\|_H<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you! I have a question: why for any permutation $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{N}$,  $(f_{\sigma(k)}:k\in\mathbb{N})$ is a Bessel sequence whenever $(f_k)$ is?